# import on NetBeans a project located in web repository

Tags: java, netbeans, web-applications

how can I import on NetBeans a web application project?
That is hosted in an web repository, in particoular:  https://zero.coremuniti.com/svn/esercitazioni-psw/Workspace-Codice/

Comment: Team -> Subversion -> Checkout -> Repository url:  https://zero.coremuniti.com/svn/esercitazioni-psw/Workspace-Codice/

Comment: Perfect! Problem solved.